# Warning messages for form validation fields are not occurring

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have created my code accordingly.

I recently changed the form action and now the form validation warnings are no longer applying on page load. For instance, if I click submit without entering data into any of the fields, I get 0 response and forwarded to the confirm.html page which should not be happening.

```js
window.onload = init;
//creation of checkRegistration method
    function checkRegistration() {
        //definition of variables
        //var checkev = 0;
        var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var passwordVerify = document.getElementById('passwordVerify').value;
        var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
        var signUpNewsletter = document.getElementById('signUpNewsletter').value;

        var userNameError = false,
            passwordError = false,
            passwordVerifyError = false,
            firstNameError = false,
            lastNameError = false,
            emailError = false,
            phoneNumberError = false;
        
        // define logic checks
        var alphaOnly = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        var alphaNum = /^(?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*$/i;
        var phoneFormat = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;
        var atrate = email.indexOf("@");
        var dot = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        
        //clearning out warniings
        document.getElementById('userNameWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('passwordWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('passwordVerifyWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('firstNameWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('lastNameWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('emailWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('phoneNumberWarning').innerHTML = "";
        
        //validation of username, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking for alphanumeric condition, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (userName == "") {
            //passes error requiring something to be entered
            document.getElementById('userNameWarning').innerHTML = "A username is required.";
            //moves cursor to this field if error occurs
            //document.pageForm.userName.focus();
            //document.pageForm.userName.select();
            //checkev=0;
            userNameError = true;
        //ensures that username meets alphanumberic regex requirements
        } else if (!userName.match(alphaNum)) {
            document.getElementById('userNameWarning').innerHTML = "Username must contain at least one letter and one number, no special characters.";
            userNameError = true;
        //passes check with no error and increments checkev
        //else {
           // document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = "";
            //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of password, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to make sure the password is at least 8 character in lenght, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (password == "") {
            //passes error requiring something to be entered
            document.getElementById('passwordWarning').innerHTML = "A password is required.";
            //moves cursor to this field if error occurs
            //document.pageForm.password.focus();
            //document.pageForm.password.select();
            //checkev = 0;
            passwordError = true;
        //check if password length is 8 or more characters
        } else if (password.length <= 8) {
            document.getElementById('passwordWarning').innerHTML = "A password of at least 8 characters is required.";
            passwordError = true;
        //else {
            //document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = "";
            //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of passwordVerify, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to be sure that password verify matches password, inherently verifying that the password needs to be 8 characters in length, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (passwordVerify == "" ) {
            document.getElementById('passwordVerifyWarning').innerHTML = "Please verify your password.";
            //document.pageForm.passwordVerify.focus();
            //document.pageForm.passwordVerify.select();
            //checkev = 0;
            passwordVerifyError = true;
        } else if (password != passwordVerify) {
            document.getElementById('passwordVerifyWarning').innerHTML = "Passwords do not match, password must be 8 characters.";
            passwordVerifyError = true;
        //else {
            //document.getElementById('passwordVerify').innerHTML = "";
           // checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of first name, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to see that the first name field is text only and no numerals, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (firstName == "") {
          document.getElementById('firstNameWarning').innerHTML = "Your first name is required.";
            //document.pageForm.firstName.focus();
            //document.pageForm.firstName.select();
          //checkev = 0;
            firstNameError = true;
        } else if (!(firstName.match(alphaOnly))) {
            document.getElementById('firstNameWarning').innerHTML = "Please use only letters in this field.";
            firstNameError = true;
        //else {
          //document.getElementById('firstName').innerHTML = "";
          //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of last name, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to see that the last name field is text only and no numerals, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (lastName == "") {
          document.getElementById('lastNameWarning').innerHTML = "Your last name is required.";
            //document.pageForm.lastName.focus();
            //document.pageForm.lastName.select();
           // checkev = 0;
            lastNameError = true;
        } else if (!(lastName.match(alphaOnly))) {
            document.getElementById('lastNameWarning').innerHTML = "Please use only letters in this field.";
            lastNameError = true;
        //else {
         // document.getElementById('lastName').innerHTML = "";
          //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of email
        if (email == "") {
            document.getElementById('emailWarning').innerHTML = "Your email address is required.";
           // document.pageForm.email.focus();
           // document.pageForm.email.select();
          //checkev = 0;
            emailError = true;
        } else if (atrate < 1 || dot < atrate + 2 || dot + 2 >= email.length) {
            document.getElementById('emailWarning').innerHTML = "Your email input is not valid.";
            emailError = true;
       // else {
         // document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = "";
          //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of phone number, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to see that the phonenumber should match the required phoneFormat, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (phoneNumber == "") {
            document.getElementById('phoneNumberWarning').innerHTML = "Your phone number is required.";
            //document.pageForm.phoneNumber.focus();
            //document.pageForm.phoneNumber.select();
          //checkev = 0;
            phoneNumberError = true;
        } else  if (!(phoneNumber.match(phoneFormat))) {
            document.getElementById('phoneNumberWarning').innerHTML = "Your phone number is required in (XXX) XXX-XXXX format.";
       // else {
            //document.getElementById('phoneNumber').innerHTML = "";
           // checkev++;
            phoneNumberError = true;
        }
        
        if (userNameError === true) {
            document.getElementById('userName').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (passwordError === true) {
            document.getElementById('password').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (passwordVerifyError === true) {
            document.getElementById('passwordVerify').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (firstNameError === true) {
            document.getElementById('firstName').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (lastNameError === true) {
            document.getElementById('lastName').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (emailError === true) {
            document.getElementById('email').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (phoneNumberError === true) {
            document.getElementById('phoneNumber').focus();
            return false;

        }
        
        //validation of sign up for newsletter, checking to see if there is nothing 
}
```

```html
<form id="pageForm">
        <form action="/registration.html" onsubmit=checkRegistration() method="get">
            <label for="userName">Username:</label><label2 id="userNameWarning"></label2>
            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Enter your Username" />
            <!--<span class="error" id="userName"></span><br><br>-->
            
            
            <label for="Password">Password:
            </label><label2 id="passwordWarning"></label2>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" />
            <!--<span class="error" id="password"></span><br><br>-->
            
            
            <label for="passwordVerify">Verify your Password:
            </label><label2 id="passwordVerifyWarning"></label2>
            <input type="password" name="passwordVerify" placeholder="Enter in your Password again" />
            <!--<span class="error" id="passwordVerify"></span><br><br>-->
            
            
            <label for="firstName">First Name:
            </label><label2 id="firstNameWarning"></label2>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter your First Name" />
            <!--<span class="error" id="firstName"></span><br><br>-->
            
            
            <label for="hostName">Last Name:
            </label><label2 id="lastNameWarning"></label2>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" />
            <!--<span class="error" id="lastName"></span><br><br>-->
            
            
            <label for="email">Email:
            </label><label2 id="emailWarning"></label2>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" />
            <!--<span class="error" id="email"></span><br><br>-->
   
            
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:
            </label><label2 id="phoneNumberWarning"></label2>
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" />
            <!--<span class="error" id="phoneNumber"></span><br><br>-->
            
            
   <label for="signUpNewsletter">Sign up for newsletter:
            </label>
            <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" value="Yes" checked > Yes 
            <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" value="No"> No
            <!--<br><br><span class="error" id="signUpNewsletter"></span><br><br>-->
            
            <!-- Creation of submit button-->
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction=confirm.html>
 
            </form></form></body>
```

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined"`. Also why do you have nested form tags?

Comment: You commented out the input fields with the id's so you don't have an element with `id="passwordVerify"` or `id="password"` and so on, so `document.getElementById('password').value` will not work

Comment: you need `onsubmit="return checkRegistration()"` and then `checkRegistration` should return `true` for ok and `false` for error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove `window.onload = init;` as it throws an error initially.

Second, your form tag is nested in another form tag which is completely unnecessary and prevents the form from triggering the onsubmit function which causes the error of submitted empty forms.

Lastly, your input elements don't actually have IDs, just names. So as Alon said in the comments your `document.getElementById('element').value` wont function correctly.

Try moving forward with the code snippet below as it corrects some of the main errors so you're actually hitting the validation conditions.

```js
//creation of checkRegistration method
    function checkRegistration() {
        //definition of variables
        //var checkev = 0;
        var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var passwordVerify = document.getElementById('passwordVerify').value;
        var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
        var signUpNewsletter = document.getElementById('signUpNewsletter').value;

        var userNameError = false,
            passwordError = false,
            passwordVerifyError = false,
            firstNameError = false,
            lastNameError = false,
            emailError = false,
            phoneNumberError = false;
        
        // define logic checks
        var alphaOnly = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        var alphaNum = /^(?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*$/i;
        var phoneFormat = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;
        var atrate = email.indexOf("@");
        var dot = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        
        //clearning out warniings
        document.getElementById('userNameWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('passwordWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('passwordVerifyWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('firstNameWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('lastNameWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('emailWarning').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('phoneNumberWarning').innerHTML = "";
        
        //validation of username, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking for alphanumeric condition, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (userName == "") {
            //passes error requiring something to be entered
            document.getElementById('userNameWarning').innerHTML = "A username is required.";
            //moves cursor to this field if error occurs
            //document.pageForm.userName.focus();
            //document.pageForm.userName.select();
            //checkev=0;
            userNameError = true;
        //ensures that username meets alphanumberic regex requirements
        } else if (!userName.match(alphaNum)) {
            document.getElementById('userNameWarning').innerHTML = "Username must contain at least one letter and one number, no special characters.";
            userNameError = true;
        //passes check with no error and increments checkev
        //else {
           // document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = "";
            //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of password, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to make sure the password is at least 8 character in lenght, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (password == "") {
            //passes error requiring something to be entered
            document.getElementById('passwordWarning').innerHTML = "A password is required.";
            //moves cursor to this field if error occurs
            //document.pageForm.password.focus();
            //document.pageForm.password.select();
            //checkev = 0;
            passwordError = true;
        //check if password length is 8 or more characters
        } else if (password.length <= 8) {
            document.getElementById('passwordWarning').innerHTML = "A password of at least 8 characters is required.";
            passwordError = true;
        //else {
            //document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = "";
            //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of passwordVerify, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to be sure that password verify matches password, inherently verifying that the password needs to be 8 characters in length, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (passwordVerify == "" ) {
            document.getElementById('passwordVerifyWarning').innerHTML = "Please verify your password.";
            //document.pageForm.passwordVerify.focus();
            //document.pageForm.passwordVerify.select();
            //checkev = 0;
            passwordVerifyError = true;
        } else if (password != passwordVerify) {
            document.getElementById('passwordVerifyWarning').innerHTML = "Passwords do not match, password must be 8 characters.";
            passwordVerifyError = true;
        //else {
            //document.getElementById('passwordVerify').innerHTML = "";
           // checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of first name, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to see that the first name field is text only and no numerals, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (firstName == "") {
          document.getElementById('firstNameWarning').innerHTML = "Your first name is required.";
            //document.pageForm.firstName.focus();
            //document.pageForm.firstName.select();
          //checkev = 0;
            firstNameError = true;
        } else if (!(firstName.match(alphaOnly))) {
            document.getElementById('firstNameWarning').innerHTML = "Please use only letters in this field.";
            firstNameError = true;
        //else {
          //document.getElementById('firstName').innerHTML = "";
          //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of last name, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to see that the last name field is text only and no numerals, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (lastName == "") {
          document.getElementById('lastNameWarning').innerHTML = "Your last name is required.";
            //document.pageForm.lastName.focus();
            //document.pageForm.lastName.select();
           // checkev = 0;
            lastNameError = true;
        } else if (!(lastName.match(alphaOnly))) {
            document.getElementById('lastNameWarning').innerHTML = "Please use only letters in this field.";
            lastNameError = true;
        //else {
         // document.getElementById('lastName').innerHTML = "";
          //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of email
        if (email == "") {
            document.getElementById('emailWarning').innerHTML = "Your email address is required.";
           // document.pageForm.email.focus();
           // document.pageForm.email.select();
          //checkev = 0;
            emailError = true;
        } else if (atrate < 1 || dot < atrate + 2 || dot + 2 >= email.length) {
            document.getElementById('emailWarning').innerHTML = "Your email input is not valid.";
            emailError = true;
       // else {
         // document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = "";
          //checkev++;
        }
        
        //validation of phone number, first checking to see if there is no value, then checking to see that the phonenumber should match the required phoneFormat, else the variable checkev is incremented
        if (phoneNumber == "") {
            document.getElementById('phoneNumberWarning').innerHTML = "Your phone number is required.";
            //document.pageForm.phoneNumber.focus();
            //document.pageForm.phoneNumber.select();
          //checkev = 0;
            phoneNumberError = true;
        } else  if (!(phoneNumber.match(phoneFormat))) {
            document.getElementById('phoneNumberWarning').innerHTML = "Your phone number is required in (XXX) XXX-XXXX format.";
       // else {
            //document.getElementById('phoneNumber').innerHTML = "";
           // checkev++;
            phoneNumberError = true;
        }
        
        if (userNameError === true) {
            document.getElementById('userName').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (passwordError === true) {
            document.getElementById('password').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (passwordVerifyError === true) {
            document.getElementById('passwordVerify').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (firstNameError === true) {
            document.getElementById('firstName').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (lastNameError === true) {
            document.getElementById('lastName').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (emailError === true) {
            document.getElementById('email').focus();
            return false;

        } else if (phoneNumberError === true) {
            document.getElementById('phoneNumber').focus();
            return false;

        }
        
        //validation of sign up for newsletter, checking to see if there is nothing 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf8">
    <title>tester</title>
    <body class="container">

    <form  id="pageForm" onsubmit="return checkRegistration()" action="/registration.html"  method="get">
        <label for="userName">Username:</label><label2 id="userNameWarning"></label2>
        <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Enter your Username" />
        <!--<span class="error" id="userName"></span><br><br>-->
        
        
        <label for="Password">Password:
        </label><label2 id="passwordWarning"></label2>
        <input type="password" name="password"  id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" />
        <!--<span class="error" id="password"></span><br><br>-->
        
        
        <label for="passwordVerify">Verify your Password:
        </label><label2 id="passwordVerifyWarning"></label2>
        <input type="password" name="passwordVerify"  id="passwordVerify" placeholder="Enter in your Password again" />
        <!--<span class="error" id="passwordVerify"></span><br><br>-->
        
        
        <label for="firstName">First Name:
        </label><label2 id="firstNameWarning"></label2>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id = "firstName" placeholder="Enter your First Name" />
        <!--<span class="error" id="firstName"></span><br><br>-->
        
        
        <label for="hostName">Last Name:
        </label><label2 id="lastNameWarning"></label2>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id= "lastName" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" />
        <!--<span class="error" id="lastName"></span><br><br>-->
        
        
        <label for="email">Email:
        </label><label2 id="emailWarning"></label2>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address" />
        <!--<span class="error" id="email"></span><br><br>-->
  
        
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:
        </label><label2 id="phoneNumberWarning"></label2>
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id = "phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" />
        <!--<span class="error" id="phoneNumber"></span><br><br>-->
        
        
  <label for="signUpNewsletter">Sign up for newsletter:
        </label>
        <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" value="Yes" checked > Yes 
        <input type="radio" name="signUpNewsletter" id="signUpNewsletter" value="No"> No
        <!--<br><br><span class="error" id="signUpNewsletter"></span><br><br>-->
        
        <!-- Creation of submit button-->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction=confirm.html>

        </form></body>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nesting forms is not just unnecessary; it's invalid HTML.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I am in a basics JavaScript course and in my third week. I was feeling pretty accomplished until this week. This is functioning just as I had hoped! I need to update my CSS now to properly format my new way of delivering errors. Thank you again for your assistance.